# Set SD Card as internal storage

Tags: mount, sd-card, storage

I would like to change the default storage from eMMC to SD Card in Ubuntu. I have a microSD card and a slot for this SD card on my devide (Jetson nano but not the original carrier board). My default storage is an eMMC storage of the Jetson Nano. I would like to change this so that everything I install in future is automatically stored on my SD card instead of the eMMC.

The system I use is Ubuntu 18.04.

Can anyone tell me the terminal commands or the procedure? That would be great.

---

[image: df -h]

The reason I am asking this is because for round about 1 week I had the problem that the Jetson did not boot because my eMMC storage was full. So I need to delete installed packages (strg. + alt + F2 so I had the chance to delete packages). After deleting some packages the Jetson was booting again. After that I ran a file to allow booting from the SD card. Now I would like to install the deleted packages like the package swig or the package pypylon again. But I dont want to have the booting error again. What can I do to install these packages on the sd card and not on eMMC? The eMMC is 16GB and the SD Card 128 GB. I need a way to install the packages in a different place than the eMMC. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you propose is possible. Programs are installed in default directories, so it's either one or the other. I don't think you can switch storage medium "half way". Another thing is that an eMMC is probably faster than an SD card, so this should also be taken into account.

Comment: However, what you could do is add the SD card as a data directory for some apps. Maybe include the output of `df`, so we can see your storage layout.

Comment: Can the device boot from the sdcard?

Comment: Consider a small Ubuntu release like Lubuntu for your limited space problem.  Running off an SD card works fine for my 8GB Intel Compute Stick, and it also holds data directories for another OS installed on the stick, so both methods are possible.